# Kafka - non-ZooKeeper-based consumers Vs ZooKeeper based consumers

Tags: java, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

While I am going through the documentation, I come across the following phrase
https://kafka.apache.org/20/documentation.html#basic_ops_consumer_lag

> > bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --describe --group my-group
>
> Note: This will only show information about consumers that use the
>   Java consumer API (non-ZooKeeper-based consumers).
>
> This tool also works with ZooKeeper-based consumers:
>
> bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 --describe --group my-group
>
> Note: This will only show information about consumers that use
>   ZooKeeper (not those using the Java consumer API).

What is the difference between non-ZooKeeper-based consumers Vs ZooKeeper based consumers
 - Is it  got to do with java language ( it seems java is referred in the comments ).

- Is it got to do with something like zookeeper consumer connect with zk while non zk connect with the brokers ?

PS : It seems this is not present in 2.5 documentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before Kafka 0.9, Consumers used Zookeeper for coordination. Since then, Consumers now only connect to Kafka.

For that reason, the `kafka-consumer-groups.sh` had support for showing "zookeeper-based" (ie the old consumer) group details.

The "old consumer" was deprecated in Kafka 0.11 and finally removed in 2.1.0. The `kafka-consumer-groups.sh` was also updated to remove any mention of it.

So basically, just ignore it, it's a legacy client that does not exist anymore.

Comment: ok, I hope it got nothing do with java vs non java clients . Going forward, the information could be retrieved from brokers ( bootstrap servers) ( evident from 2.5)

Comment: It mentions Java because the old clients were written in Scala. Now all clients, including third party clients written in other languages, only use Kafka.